# Make <a> tag clickable for bigger area

Tags: html, css

I have a menu, where I want my  tag to be clickable on a much bigger area on hover, basically for the width and hegiht of the menu.

This is the code I have now: http://jsfiddle.net/uwJTC/14/

**HTML**

```
<div id="box">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Basic but good</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This is a longer one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shorter</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#box ul { 
    width: 230px;
    height: 160px;
    float: right;
    margin: 0px 0 15px 900px;
    background:#999;
    list-style: none;
}

#box ul li {
    background: red;
    border: 1px solid #222;
}

#box ul li:hover {
    background: yellow;
}

#box ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

I hope you know what I mean. If you don't please ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like so? http://jsfiddle.net/Allendar/uwJTC/16/

```
#box ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```